# File handling programming with Swing in java

Tags: java, swing, file-handling

I need help with step 2 to understand the working of File handling in java,,,,...

This is what i am doing.... :-
problem: Exception
Note: i am a newbie with this concept to please tell me what is wrong in my code.

-Create a mini Java application using swing, which must ask for a Username and Password and have a create button.

-as soon as the create button is pressed a new directory must be created with the name of the user and password must be saved as password.txt file inside that directory.

-if the directory already exists, then a pop-up windows should appear saying "User already exists".

I've tried for hours now but can't do it properly, little help is much appreciated.

I need to see some code for this, while i am continuously trying to fix mine.

### Updated Code :

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;

class CreateUser implements ActionListener
{   
    JFrame fr;  //Frame
    JButton b1;  //Create Button
    JLabel lb1, lb2;    //Username and password
    JTextField tf1, tf2;    //Username and password input fields
    JPanel p1;

    CreateUser()
    {
        //Setting the frame
        fr=new JFrame();
        fr.setLayout(null);
        fr.setSize(400,400);

        //setting panel
        p1=new JPanel();
        p1.setBounds(0,0,400,400);
        p1.setLayout(null);

        //setting Username Label
        JLabel lb1=new JLabel("Username: ");
        lb1.setBounds(50,50,70,30);
        p1.add(lb1);

        //setting Username Text Field
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf1.setBounds(150,50,150,30);
        p1.add(tf1);


        //setting Password Label
        JLabel lb2=new JLabel("Password: ");
        lb2.setBounds(50,100,70,30);
        p1.add(lb2);

        //setting Password Text Field
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf2.setBounds(150,100,150,30);
        p1.add(tf2);

        //setting Button
        b1=new JButton("Create");
        b1.setBounds(100,200,100,40);   
        p1.add(b1);

        fr.add(p1);
        fr.setVisible(true);    
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        tf1.addActionListener(this);
        tf2.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new CreateUser();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==b1)
        {   
            {
                String uid = tf1.getText();
                String pass = tf2.getText();

                String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

                //Creating a new folder Users

                File file = new File(dir+"\\users");
                if (!file.exists()) 
                {
                    if (file.mkdir()) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Directory is created!");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
                    }
                }
                dir = dir+"\\users";

                //Creating a folder named with username inside Users folder

                File file1 = new File(dir+"\\"+uid);
                if (!file1.exists()) 
                {
                    if (file1.mkdir()) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Directory is created!");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Failed to create directory!");
                    }
                }

                //Storing Password.txt inside users/username folder

                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("password.txt");
                    byte b[]=pass.getBytes();
                    fout.write(b);
                }
                catch(Exception ee)
                {}
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  _"I need to see some code for this"_ -- sorry, StackOverflow does not work this way.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You are expected to post _your_ code and explain what errors you are getting and what isn't working.

Comment: Sorry but rather than excuses, you really **must** post your pertinent code. Otherwise how will we understand your problem? Best to create and post a valid [mcve]. Please read this valuable link.

Comment: People would be more willing to help you if you posted your code. It doesn't matter how new you are. They will help. No one will make fun of you if that is your concern.

Comment: Also I'm sure that you understand that this site is not a code-writing service, but rather a question/answer site. We'll be more than happy to answer well-written questions about specific problems, but your current question as written reads like a code request, and this alone will get the question closed. Again, improve the question, show your code, and write as specific a question as possible. Good luck!

Comment: Even if it's badly formatted we can fix it here (not the idea, or you can paste it into your favourite IDE (eclipse / netbeans / etc) and clic on "Format code" or whatever the option is called, then copy-paste it here). Even if variables are not the best we're gonna help you, but you **must** place your code here, so we can see **your** effort into solving the problem and we can fix the error(s) it may have. Nobody starts knowing everything, so don't be afraid of making a mistake

Comment: Check out the Java Swing tutorials, and the api documentation at [Oracle/Java site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) particularly JFileChooser class.

Comment: Also rather than trying to tackle everything at once, you're far better off dividing the big problem into its small constituent steps and then trying to solve each step, one at a time, often in isolation. These steps can include the GUI portion and the file input/output portions. Then if you still get stuck, you can ask a much more specific question, one that can receive a much more specific and helpful answer.

Comment: Post code your code please.

Comment: Alright guys, i added that code..

Comment: `"I need help with step 2 to understand the working of File handling in java,..."` -- that's still pretty broad. Again I suggest that you create a new program, one without a GUI, one that has a simple single main method, one that tries to create a new directory and file and that places the information in that file. Again "divide and conquer". Then if still stuck, show us that code and ask your *specific* question about just what confuses you.

Comment: You'll find similar problems/answers [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+create+directory+and+write+file)

Comment: I understand what you mean sir @HovercraftFullOfEels, i am half way through this swing code so i will go with it, but i will update the entire program and then ask specific questions, sorry for being a mess, this is my first time here :) , hope i don't bother anyone.

Comment: No bother, but you may be coming too soon. You always want to post a valid good faith attempt at solving your problem with your question, or closest that you can get to this. If you haven't even tried the file handling code yet, then you're here prematurely.

Comment: Updated the code, i have tried a few problems @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: What problems are you seeing? A NullPointerException perhaps?

Comment: yes :/ @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many potential problems here so let's go through the code:

```
class CreateUser implements ActionListener {
```

Minor problem: avoid having your GUI classes implement your control interfaces. This gives the class too much responsibility, cluttering the class, leading to unwieldy difficult to debug code. Better to use an anonymous inner class or non-anonymous inner class.

```
JFrame fr; // Frame
JButton b1; // Create Button
JLabel lb1, lb2; // Username and password
JTextField tf1, tf2; // Username and password input fields
JPanel p1;
```

Minor problem: the fields should always be private unless you've a specific reason to make the public. You don't, so make them private here.

```
CreateUser() {
    // Setting the frame
    fr = new JFrame();
    fr.setLayout(null);
    fr.setSize(400, 400);
```

Minor problem: Never, never, never use `null` layouts. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

```
    // setting panel
    p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
    p1.setLayout(null);
```

Same problem. Learn the layout managers, and then **use** the layout managers.

```
    // setting Username Text Field
    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
```

**Major problem**: You're shadowing a field here. By re-declaring the tf1 variable within the class constructor, you're assigning a JTextField object to a ***local*** variable, which means that the tf1 field in the class remains empty/unassigned/null. This can lead to a NullPointerException being called if you ever try to use this null field.

So if you're going to do the object creation and assignments within the constructor or an init method, then instead of

```
    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();
```

do:

```
    tf1 = new JTextField(); 


    // setting Password Text Field
    JTextField tf2 = new JTextField();
```

Same problem. Also this should be a JPasswordField not a JTextField.

```
    // setting Button
    b1 = new JButton("Create");
```

For some reason you assign the button correctly. Go figure.

```
public static void main(String s[]) {
    new CreateUser();
}
```

Always start a Swing application on the Swing event thread or EDT (for Event Dispatch Thread). So do:

```
public static void main(String s[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new CreateUser());        
}
```

---

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("password.txt");
    byte b[] = pass.getBytes();
    fout.write(b);
} catch (Exception ee) {

}
```

Major problem: never never have an empty catch block which is the coding equivalent of trying to drive a car with a blindfold on. At least print out the stacktrace so you will be notified of errors if and when they occur.  Also, if you're writing out text, use a writer such as a PrintWriter. I won't go into the dangers of writing out password text, but obviously it's something you'd never do in real life.

Comment: Thank you very much, It helped me learn a lot today. Thank you very much!

Comment: Bro, i got error on using JPasswordFields


C:\Users\Mukul\Desktop\JJava>javac CreateUser.java

Note: CreateUser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning, just ignore it